# QWebView. Запуск python-кода по ссылке

Tags: python, qt

Есть примерно такой код:

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl

html = u'''
   <ul class="nav">
     <li><a href="index.pyw">Главная</a></li>
     <li><a href="link/index.php">Ссылка 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="link/index2.php">Ссылка 2</a></li>
   </ul><br />'''


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

browser = QWebView()
browser.setHtml(html)

browser.show()

app.exec_()
```

Можно ли как-то запустить python-код при нажатии на ссылку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализуйте класс-обработчик, содержащий в слоте ваш `python`-код, который вы хотите запускать при активации ссылки.

Соедините этот слот с сигналом `void QWebView::linkClicked(const QUrl& url)`.

Для того, чтобы этот сигнал отправлялся необходимо установить у `QWebPage` вашего `QWebView` свойство `linkDelegationPolicy` в значение `DelegateAllLinks`.

Всё вместе в коде:

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView, QWebPage
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl, QObject, pyqtSlot, SIGNAL, SLOT

class Handler(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)

    @pyqtSlot("QUrl")
    def slotActivateLink(self, url):
        print("Debug: " + url.toString() + " activated") # Здесь на ваш код замените

html = u'''
   <ul class="nav">
     <li><a href="index.pyw">Главная</a></li>
     <li><a href="link/index.php">Ссылка 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="link/index2.php">Ссылка 2</a></li>
   </ul><br />'''


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

browser = QWebView()
browser.page().setLinkDelegationPolicy(QWebPage.DelegateAllLinks)

handler = Handler()
QObject.connect(browser, SIGNAL("linkClicked(const QUrl&)"), handler, SLOT("slotActivateLink(const QUrl&)"))

browser.setHtml(html)
browser.show()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Отличный код.
Только не могу сообразить как код:
`browser = QWebView()
browser.setHtml(html)
browser.show()` выполнить внутри слота slotActivateLink?

Comment: Что конкретно вы хотите сделать в слоте? Какой результат нужен?

Comment: Чтобы при нажатии на ссылку открылось новое окно созданное при помощи browser.setHtml(html)

Comment: Тогда в коде слота нужно создать это окно:`def slotActivateLink(self, url):    subrowser = QWebView(self)    subrowser.setHtml(html)    subrowser.show()`

Comment: `def slotActivateLink(self, url):
        bro = QWebView()
        bro.setHtml(u'''<a href="index.pyw">Главная 2</a>''')
        bro.show()` - При клике ничего не происходит

Comment: Ну конечно. А кто объекту `bro` будет свойство `linkDelegationPolicy` устанавливать?

Comment: Зачем здесь это свойство? Думаю я нашел решение

Comment: Здравствуйте. Есть еще вопрос. Как можно с вами связаться?

Comment: Если ещё актуально, пишите на почту: pk.al@mail.ru